# Javascript: Monitor HTML5 audio element's audio data

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Is there a way to get current `<audio>` element's peak value while playing the audio stream? In other words, to monitor the audio data while playing. Something like:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
setInterval(function(){
   console.log(audio.peakValue); 
},200);
```

Of course there is nothing like peakValue in HTML5 audio API, but is there a way to get this with Javascript?

Comment: Are you talking about an [`AnalyserNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) ?

Comment: Well this seems great, with the only exception that it is not supported in IE, according to their own list. But thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido Internet Explorer is a real browser, just not one that supports the Web Audio API.

Comment: @Kaiido You'll get no argument from me that IE is a pain to work with.  For many of my web applications I simply don't support it, as I'm fortunate to have a user base that has relatively few IE users.  But, I would never take the attitude that IE isn't a real browser, as it is and real people use it.  Sometimes the answer is that you can't reasonably add support for IE, but the elitist tone that I read into your comment (and forgive me if that was not your intent) is one that I find frustrating among web developers.  We should strive to make things work for all our users, when it is possible.

Comment: Well, unfortunately in my case I will have to treat IE as a browser, since this is about an app supposed to work in it too (not because I want it:) ). So, I was wondering if there is a fallback solution. Similar as browsers that don't have a WebRTC support use a Flash fallback for camera streaming.